# How can I return different type according to the value of parameter in C++?

Tags: c++, boost, overloading, rtti, boost-any

I want to do something overload with different value of parameter in C++.

Something like dynamic language such as Python:

```
def foo(str):
  if str == "a":
    return str
  if str == "b":
    return true
  if str == "c":
    return 1
```

Is there some pattern of RTTI in C++ to make it work?

Boost::any needs implict define type when call the function:

```
boost::any foo() {...}

auto result = boost::any_cast<int>(foo("c"));
```

How can I define result var without implict give 'int'?

In other words, I want to make this semantics below:

```
result = foo("a")
```

Comment: `boost::variant`, `boost::any`.

Comment: coming from strictly typed languages, can you give me an example where this is really useful? I'm not convinced I would like to call a function with an ambiguous return value.

Comment: Since C++ is typed, programmers work to return, well, things of one type. Anything else gets really hairy. (How do you handle such a value?)

Comment: There are of course ways to achieve this but it is rarely justified, you might just complicate things more than necessary. If this is about error handling you might want to change your approach and use exceptions or error codes.

Comment: @Alex This particular combination (string, bool, int) looks suspicious, but this looks like a simple factory function to me if `str`, `true` and `1` were objects implementing the same interface. @xunzhang, what do you intend to do with the result of foo?

Comment: I'm honestly curious what both sides X and Y are in this problem.

Comment: @Alex Why ambiguous? You can check the type of the returned value.

Comment: @user1095108 that's exactly what I don't want to do! The textbook example of a function that returns objects of different type is a factory. Factories return objects that implement a common interface. This way you don't need to know the precise type to use it.

Comment: @Alex But `int` and `bool` are fundamental types, you'd have to make a wrapper around them. Not to mention, that you may not have control over `string` either. You'd also probably need `dynamic_cast`s and hence `rtti`, lots of bloat.

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of languages that allow what you are asking for:

- dynamic languages
- dependently typed languages

C++ is neither: a function signature never depends upon the value of the arguments passed to it. It may, however, depend on the type of the arguments or the value of non-type template parameters:

```
struct A{}; struct B{}; struct C{};

auto foo(A) -> std::string;
auto foo(B) -> bool;
auto foo(C) -> int;
```

If you really wish a runtime choice of the right type, then statically the result type of the function is the union of the types it can return; this can be expressed cleanly using `boost::variant` (which is syntactic sugar for a tagged union):

```
auto foo(std::string const&) -> boost::variant<bool, int, std::string>;
```

Of course, it means the result it `boost::variant<bool, int, std::string>` and not either one of those three; which is exactly what we want. It is then up to the user to check the actual type, and if you read the documentation you'll see there are multiple ways of doing so.

Comment: Does boost::varient support std::vector<std::string>?

Comment: @xunzhang: `boost::variant` supports any type, even types which (like `std::string` or `std::vector<T>`) handle memory, and thus require proper invocation of copy construction, copy assignment and destruction. It'll even support `std::map<std::string, std::vector<CustomType>>` if you wish :)

Comment: My problem is How can I convert a boost::variant<int, bool> type to a int type?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use a union inside a struct with a type field.

```
enum var_type{X_BOOL,X_INT,X_DOUBLE,X_STRING /*add more if needed*/};

struct var{
  var_type type;
  union{
    bool bool_var;
    int int_var;
    double dbl_var;
    string str_var;
    /*add more here if needed...*/
  }var;
};
```

when you set the var you have to set also the type, and when you get this as return value, you should check the type and take the var according to it.

Comment: You are re-implementing `boost::variant`, badly.

Comment: The point is: how to do it, I did not intended to supply a full implementation. sure you can add setters as: setInt, setBool, setString etc. and getters, and also throw exceptions in case you use it wrong...